# .htaccess redirection to a specific page on a different domain

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Good day

I'm trying to redirect all page requests on http://kempstonacademy.co.za to http://kempston.co.za/driver-academy

I've used the following in my .htaccess file to redirect to a specific page on another site:
**Redirect permanent / http://kempston.co.za/driver-academy**

The problem is that when someone browses to any of the pages other than the home page, it redirects to **http://kempston.co.za/driver-academy** but appends the specified page to the end of the URL. In other words, **http://kempstonacademy.co.za/benefits** redirects to **http://kempston.co.za/driver-academybenefits**.

Many thanks for your help.

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Redirect` use `RedirectMatch` to make sure you always redirect to target page:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^ http://kempston.co.za/driver-academy
```

Comment: I've updated as suggested but now all the pages get Not Found error.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help, it's working exactly as I need it to.